# Load a form into a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a panel and a button, when I click the button I want to load a form inside the panel.

This is how i'm loading the form into the panle

```
Dim f As New Form()
f.TopLevel = False
f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
f.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
f.Visible = True
Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
```

My problem is once the form loads, everything is stretched. Controls do not look like what they are in the form once it loads inside the panel. I tried making the form smaller than the panel, still stretched. I also tried not maximizing the window in the panel and just using `Sizable` Border

Comment: I also tried the with mock project and the controls are loaded with their default sizing. I set the form property to the exact same value and the form loaded with the controls with their sizes retained to the same as specified in design mode. Did you check the control's `Anchor` property setting to see if you have customised it?

Answer (score 4):

I tried your code and I saw the form inside the panel maximized, So I only put this line:

```
f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
```

before setting the visible to true with the button.

```
Public f As New Form()
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    f.TopLevel = False
    f.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
    f.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 150)
    f.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    f.Visible = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If f.Visible = False Then f.Visible = True Else f.Visible = False
End Sub
```

[Screenshot of what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6SOT.png) because I don't have enough reputation to post image (my first answer with stackoverflow). You can see the panel in green. I set the BorderStyle like that just to show you the result but it's working with property to None and added Size/Location to position the form.
Hope this ll help you.